# Writing a software book with LaTex - General Advise

Tags: chapters, book-design

I am a so new to Tex and I am trying to learn now.

I decided to write a so simple software ***(ASP.NET 4.0)*** book for myself to learn it with a real example. So, I have the following structure for now :

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %this will support Turkish chars

\begin{document}

\section*{Getting Started With Something}

\subsection*{Headings in the `article' Document Style}

\end{document}
```

So, it is so basic as you can see. So far, I only figured out :

- How to begin and end a document
- How to set sections and subsections w/o numbers
- how to get to a new page

So, How can I define chapters?

Also, first off all I would like to have a **CONTENTS** section which will displays the chapters, sections, subsections and their page numbers. What is the best way of doing that?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! For the "Contents"  section (or rather, chapter), have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1605/making-a-table-of-contents-for-a-book.

Comment: @lockstep thanks a lot for the greeting and the answer :)

Comment: You may even upvote the answers in my link. :-)

Comment: You might want to consult some general resources about LaTeX (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-is-the-best-book-to-start-learning-latex) and come back with specific questions once you've understood the basics.

Comment: @JosephWright I think that the question is specific. I just wanted to know what is the common way of defining chapters and contents. thanks for the advice as well.

Comment: You can use `\chapter` to produce chapters. Using `\tableofcontents` (and compiling twice), you'll get a table of contents. You can find basic documentation in, for example, [A short introduction to LaTeX 2e](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lshort).

Comment: As Gonzalo said.  You might also consider the [memoir](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) documentclass for additional and usually more customizable settings compared to book.  The documentation I linked to is pretty thorough and should answer any such questions you might have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Welcome to TeX.sx](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) once more! Now that you have some basic knowledge with regard to the `\chapter` and `\tableofcontents` commands, you should consult some of the [LaTeX resources](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-is-the-best-book-to-start-learning-latex) that Joseph pointed out in his comment. For specific questions, always try to add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.