# Table of contents doesn't get created

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I am trying to create a table of contents, but it doesn't show up. I use the beamer documentclass. My code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\usetheme[secheader]{Boadilla}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\title{...}
\author{...}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
        \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Section1}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{Section2}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to compile it atleast *two* times to get the TOC.

Comment: I just compiled the example document given by you and all worked out fine for me. TOC showed up after the second compilation.

Comment: Compilation: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1606/510

Comment: Then something must be not ok here. I compiled it at least three times and it still doesn't show up.

Comment: Is a non-empty `.toc` (auxiliary) file created?

Comment: Are you sure not having enabled some "automatic clean up" action after the compilation? What are you using for compiling the file?

Comment: Ah, I got it now. I used "Latex->DVI->PDF" as my output profile in TeXnic. When I take "Latex->PDF" everything works fine. I must admit I just started with latex today. Nevertheless thank you! :)